# Use the fact that $g(x) = f(Ax+b)$ is convex to prove convexity of $\log(1+\exp(-ac^Tx))$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a convex function on $\mathbb R^m$ and let $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb R^m$ be given. I have managed to show that the function $g(x) := f(Ax+b)$ is a convex function on $\mathbb R^n$.

However, the next part requires me to use this result to prove that the function $g : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by
$$g(x)=\log(1+\exp(-ac^Tx))$$
for a given $a\in\mathbb R, c\in\mathbb R^n$ is convex on $\mathbb R^n$.

I am not sure how to proceed further. I understand that we need to come up with a convex function $f, A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb R^m$ such that $f(Ax+b)=g(x)$ but I am not sure how to do this. Will the $A, b$ we choose be in terms of the given $a, c$ in the question? Any hint or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** First show that $\log\left(1+\exp(x)\right)$ is convex.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks for your hint! I managed to solve it by simply letting $m = 1$.